# Не загружается страница/Массив копирует другой массив

Tags: javascript

*Вопрос решен, спасибо*

Имеется код

```
var sample='dddddttqdsssssssssssdd';
var sampleSplit=sample.split('');
var arr1=[];
var arr2=[];
var aa=0;
var ab=0;
var ac=0;

arr1[0]=sampleSplit[0];
arr1[1]=1;

for(i=0; i<sampleSplit.length; i++){
if(sampleSplit[aa]==sampleSplit[aa+1]){
arr1[ab+1]++;
aa++;
}
if(sampleSplit[aa]!=sampleSplit[aa+1]){
arr1[ab+2]=sampleSplit[aa+1];
arr1[ab+3]=1;
ab+=2;
aa++;
}
}
arr1.pop(arr1.length-1);
arr1.pop(arr1.length);
ab=2;
aa=0;
ac=0;
arr2=arr1;

for(e=0; e<arr2.length; e++){
for(j=0; j<arr2.length; j++){
    if(arr2[aa]==arr2[ab]){
        arr2[aa+1]+=arr2[ab+1];
        arr2.splice(ab, 2);
    }
    ab+=2;
}
}
```

Функция сначала делает из ряда одинаковых символов сжатый ряд, к примеру: было `dddddddttddddt`, стало `d,7,t,2,d,4,t,1`.

Потом она убирает повторяющиеся элементы и складывает их, то есть, из вышеупомянутого получается `d,11,t,3` (но это не получается).

Два вопроса:

1. Почему первый массив становится равным второму, хотя это указано лишь один раз и то, после того, как массив 1 заполнен.
2. Почему после добавления такой строки

   `aa+=2;`
   в конец последнего цикла страница перестает загружаться?

Пожалуйста, объясните проблему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Сложные структуры в JS это ссылки и приравнивания вида arr1 = arr2, просто копируют ссылку на arr2 в переменную arr1. Получается, вы работаете с одним массивом, просто по разному обращаетесь к нему.

Для вашей же задачи легче использовать объект, с ключем - буква, значение - кол-во потворений.

```js
const string = 'abcdabcdghhh'
const counts = {}

for (const letter of string) {
  if (counts[letter] === undefined) {
    counts[letter] = 0
  }
  
  counts[letter]++
}

console.log(counts)
```

Comment: Это уже исправили, спасибо

Comment: Я дополнил немного.

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы скопировать массив и чтобы он не менял первый нужно использовать метод slice. Если ты сделаешь просто присваивание то он будет ссылаться к первому и все изменения будут касаться обоих;  Сделай так: 
var sampleSplit = sample.slice(); 
Насчет второго вопроса тебе нужно по другому это сделать, у тебя там просто жесть!

Comment: Тогда каким образом можно объединить повторяющиеся символы из всей строчки в один? Помимо того, что у меня есть, в голову ничего не приходит

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решился путем изменения последней части на это

```
 for(e=0; e!=arr2.length; e+=2){
 for(j=0; j<arr2.length; j++){
     if(arr2[aa]==arr2[ab]){
         arr2[aa+1]+=arr2[ab+1];
     arr2.splice(ab, 2);
     }
     ab+=2;
}
aa+=2;
ab=(aa+2);
}
```